# How do I echo an image stored as a blob in my database?

Tags: php, mysql, image, blob, echo

I was just wondering what the PHP code is to echo an image I've stored in a particular table of my database.

Comment: Are you saved the image path in database or image data?

Comment: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525830/displaying-an-image-stored-in-a-mysql-blob`

Answer (score 2):

Well, here is the html you want for the image:

```
<img src="image_render.php?image_id=4" /> <!-- or any unique identifier for that image -->
```

in `image_render.php` you will want to do the following:

```
// get the image information base on the unique identifier passed in the URL
 header("Content-Type: image/png"); // tell the browser that this is an image
 echo $imageBlog; // this is what you took from the database
```

Make sure you don't add extra output in this file, or things will go bad.

That's about it.

**Note**

In most situations it is better/faster to simply store the image location on the server instead of the whole image, so you probably need to document yourself a bit more before making this decision.

Here is a discussion about the [advantages and disadvantages of storing images in the database](http://forums.asp.net/t/1096999.aspx), and [another one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613898/what-about-storing-images-in-sql-server).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I hope echo html_entity_decode($blobfield) will help you to write image if it is uploaded using any editor.

Answer (score 0):

According to another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13225757/1882885) on a [similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225726/i-need-my-php-page-to-show-my-blob-image-from-mysql-database/13225757#13225757) here on SO,

```
echo "<dt><strong>Technician Image:</strong></dt><dd>" . 
 '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.
  base64_encode($row2['image']).
  '" width="290" height="290">' . "</dd>";
```

*Do try to search before posting.